# Referencing Outlet

Tags: ios, xcode, iboutlet

I created new file .h and when I drag the 'New Referencing Outlet' line over `drawImageView`, it won't highlight.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface JCDrawView : UIView
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *drawImageView;
@end
```

Comment: your Source View's class (in IB) is JCDrawView? You are dragging to an UIImageView?

Comment: Are you sure that the UI element is of type `UIImageView`? Check this first.

Answer (score 2):

First, open your xib and select its root view.

[image]

Then, verify that the class of this view if of type `MyCustomView` (`JCDrawView` in your case).

[image]

Now, the image view can be referenced through the outlet in the view you've created.

**NOTE** `MyCustomView` class is the same as `JCDrawView`.